# Removing duplicate elements within a pandas cell and counting the number of elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Destinations
Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam
Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York
Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan
```

I want to get the following dataframe (without space between the cities):

```
Destinations_2                         no_destinations
Paris,Oslo,Milan,Athens,Amsterdam      5
Boston,New York,London,Paris           4
Nice,Paris,Milan                       3
```

How to remove duplicates within a cell?

Comment: is that 1 column or a csv file?

Comment: it is 1 column, not csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension which is faster than using `apply()` (replace `Col` with the original column name) :

```
df['no_destinations']=[len(set([a.strip() for a in i.split(',')])) for i in df['Col']]
print(df)
```

---

```
                                              Col  no_destinations
0       Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam                5
1  Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York                4
2             Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan                3
```

Comment: can I also somehow create the column without duplicate destinations

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz is order important?

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz try with `df['de_duped']=[','.join(set([a.strip() for a in i.split(',')])) for i in df['Col']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['no_destinations'] = df.Destinations.str.split(',').apply(set).apply(len)
```

if there are spaces in between use

```
df.Destinations.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: list(map(str.strip,x))).apply(set).apply(len)
```

**Output**

```
                                     Destinations  nodestinations
0       Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam               5
1  Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York               4
2             Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan               3
```

Comment: hmm, the rows needs strip. check the second `Boston` :)

Comment: ya i assumed it might be a typo..thanks bud appreciate it @anky_91

Answer (score 1):

```py
# your data:
import pandas as pd

data = {'Destinations': ['Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam',
                         'Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York',
                         'Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>>
                                      Destinations
0        Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam
1   Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York
2              Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan
```

**First**: make every row of your column a list.

```
df.Destinations = df.Destinations.apply(lambda x: x.replace(', ', ',').split(','))

>>>
                                           Destinations
0        [Paris, Oslo, Paris, Milan, Athens, Amsterdam]
1   [Boston, New York, Boston, London, Paris, New York]
2              [Nice, Paris, Milan, Paris, Nice, Milan]
```

**Second**: removes dups from the lists

```
df.Destinations = df.Destinations.apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))

# or: df.Destinations = df.Destinations.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

>>>
                               Destinations
0   [Paris, Oslo, Milan, Athens, Amsterdam]
1         [Boston, New York, London, Paris]
2                      [Nice, Paris, Milan]
```

**Finally**, create desired columns

```
df['no_destinations'] = df.Destinations.apply(lambda x: len(x))

df['Destinations_2'] = df.Destinations.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

All steps use the `apply` and `lambda` functions, you can chain or nest them together if you want

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers have addressed only one part of your problem i.e. to show the unique count (`no_destinations`). Let me try to answer both of your queries.

The idea below is to apply a method on the `Destinations` column which returns 2 series named `Destinations_2` and `no_destinations` which contain unique elements separated by comma with no space, and count of unique elements, respectively.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Destinations': ['Paris,Oslo, Paris,Milan, Athens,Amsterdam', 
                'Boston,New York, Boston,London, Paris,New York',
                'Nice,Paris, Milan,Paris, Nice,Milan'
    ]}

def remove_dups(x):
    data = set(x.replace(" ", "").split(','))
    return pd.Series([','.join(data),len(data)], index=['Destinations_2', 'no_destinations'])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df[['Destinations_2', 'no_destinations']] = df['Destinations'].apply(remove_dups)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

[image]

Note: As you are not concerned with the order, I have used `set` above. If you need to maintain the order, you will have to replace `set` with some other logic to remove duplicates.